# sudo ssh: load pubkey Permission denied

Tags: ssh, permissions, sudo, su, key-authentication

**user1** needs to be able to su to **user2** on **host1**, and then ssh to **host2** using public key authentication. The key is in `/home/user2/.ssh/id_rsa` on host1. It works with `sudo -s`...

```
[user1@host1] $ sudo -u user2 -s
[user2@host1] $ ssh host2
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-70-generic x86_64)
...
Last login: ...
[user2@host2] $
```

But this does not work...

```
[user1@host1] $ sudo -u user2 ssh host2
load pubkey "/home/user2/.ssh/id_rsa": Permission denied
load pubkey "/home/user2/.ssh/id_rsa": Permission denied
load pubkey "/home/user2/.ssh/id_dsa": Permission denied
load pubkey "/home/user2/.ssh/id_dsa": Permission denied
load pubkey "/home/user2/.ssh/id_ecdsa": Permission denied
load pubkey "/home/user2/.ssh/id_ecdsa": Permission denied
load pubkey "/home/user2/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk": Permission denied
load pubkey "/home/user2/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk": Permission denied
load pubkey "/home/user2/.ssh/id_ed25529": Permission denied
load pubkey "/home/user2/.ssh/id_ed25529": Permission denied
load pubkey "/home/user2/.ssh/id_ed25529_sk": Permission denied
load pubkey "/home/user2/.ssh/id_ed25529_sk": Permission denied
load pubkey "/home/user2/.ssh/id_xmss": Permission denied
load pubkey "/home/user2/.ssh/id_xmss": Permission denied
user2@host2's password:
```

The question is, why?

Comment: Could you doebl check, please, that the error messages that you get actually refer to the home directory of `user2` and not to the home directory of `user1`?

Comment: Yes, it refers to the home directory of `user2` and not to the home directory of `user1`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I copied my ssh keys over from my external drive to my new machine.

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
chmod u=rw,go= ~/.ssh/*
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

Comment: You know that your first two commands are identical, right? Could you explain why using `sudo -u user2 -s` followed by `ssh host2` worked but using `sudo -u user2 ssh host2` did not, and how this resolves that issue?

Comment: What does this do exactly?